# Как сделать интернет слайдер как на картинке?

Tags: java, android

Всем привет,в моем приложение нужно реализовать такой слайдер как на
картинке,данные берутся из бд,подскажите в какую сторону копать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что именно на картинке является "слайдером"?

Comment: В сторону [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).

Comment: блок с картинками

Comment: Если вы по поводу вкладок вверху, то в сторону TabLayout, если по поводу Категорий в распродаже, то в сторону ExpandableListView.

Comment: А если нужен индикатор (точки), то [сюда](http://www.androprogrammer.com/2015/06/view-pager-with-circular-indicator.html). Ну или можете что-нибудь готовое использовать.

Comment: Видите, никто не понимает, что именно тут слайдер. Обозначьте его на картинке как-нибудь.

Comment: @metalurgus, Так автор же выше уже пояснил.

Comment: @post_zeew, не нифига не понятно)Картинок много на экране)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `ExpandableListView`, где Распродажа - будет `header`, а Одежда, Обувь, Аксессуары - `childs`, для этого header.

Comment: Спасибо все понятно!

Comment: Я почти уверен, что вопрос был не насчет того, про что вы написали

Comment: @metalurgus вполне возможно )))